# searching two patterns and keep pattern1 and lines between pattern1 and pattern2

Tags: search, design-patterns, awk

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q95B4.png)

input and out as this

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: What are the patterns you're searching for?   The input and output could be achieved with grep:  `grep -A1 "abc\|arc" input`

Comment: Please post the data as text (and use that `{}` for it). `awk foo.png` just won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below egrep command -

```
#egrep 'abc|arc' -A 1 kk.txt
>ATxx abc def AA
ATGC/DNAsequence
--
>ATxx arc def AA
ATGC/DNAsequence
```